# MYSQL,can we increase the size of stored procedure name from 64 characters to let say 128 characters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have some stored procedures  that are being migrated from MS SQL SERVER to MY SQL the issue i am facing currently is some of my store procedures have very long names,so i am getting the following error while creating the stored procedure:
**ERROR 1059: Identifier name 'XXXXXXXXXXXX_XXX_XXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXX_By_XXXXXXX_And_XXXXXXX' is too long**

is there a workaround to this exception or should i rename my stored procedure to some new name in that case i would be required to  change code as well.

Comment: Why not have a table that stores information about your sprocs, then the sprocs themselves can have short, sensible names.

Comment: I tried to named the stored procedures in a way that they should depicts the functionality that is written under it,so if we want to change some functionality one can easily point out that this stored procedure/s needs to be updated,but your suggestion is a very good idea indeed,if some other suggestions or answers isn't posted in the next couple of hours,i would consider this as my only option,but my stored procedures count is more that 1000 and it is going to take some time.hope it makes sense.